# Socket Feeder Exits

Tags: c#, sockets

I have an console application, which waits for client to be connected specified socket, after that accepts client, starts feeding data, if after a while client application stops, distributer exit itself, but I would make distributer just change mode in listen for client, when client connection lost, distributer just start for waiting but meanwhile exits.

```
 static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Start()           
    }
}
private void Start()
    {            
        WaitForClientConnection();
       //waits till client connect
       StartReceive();
    }
private void WaitForClientConnection()
    {            
        _tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _tcpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.192.40"), 7000));
        _tcpSocket.Listen(100);
        _tcpClientAcceptSocket = _tcpSocket.Accept();           
    }
public void StartReceive()
    {           
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting to receive data...");
            while (_tcpClient.Connected)
            {
               //sendind data to client

            }
            if (!_tcpClient.Connected)
            {
            // if client socket listener is stops somehow, I also close _tcpClient connection after that start to keep waiting for clients
            Console.WriteLine("Closing the connection...");
            _tcpClient.Close();   
            //here start(), and  WaitForClientConnection() are begin again(I realized and sure) however in WaitForClientConnection() function exits itself from application not wait for client
            Start();

            }
        }   
    }
```

What could be the problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke WaitForClientConnection() the second time, you try to bind a new listening socket to 172.16.192.40:7000. You already have a socket bound to that address, from the first invocation of WaitForClientConnection().

Try something like this:

```
private void CreateListener()
   {
   _tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
   _tcpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.192.40"), 7000));
   _tcpSocket.Listen(100);
    }
private void Start()
   {
   if (_tcpSocket == null)
      {
      CreateListener();
      }
   WaitForClientConnection();
   //waits till client connect
   StartReceive();
   }
private void WaitForClientConnection()
   {            
    _tcpClientAcceptSocket = _tcpSocket.Accept();           
   }
```

Really you could get rid of WaitForClientConnection entirely, since it's now a single line of code. But then this is not how I'd write this; I was just trying to stay close to your original code.

The key point is that you create the listening socket once. It doesn't go away when you accept a conversation.

I don't know if this is the only issue. You should be catching and reporting exceptions, so we'd know exactly what was terminating the process.